# Concatenate multiple fields on Oracle NetSuite

Tags: concatenation, netsuite

I would like to create a workflow to concatenate 3 diferent fields, the first and second ones are list/record's type, and the third and last one is a text field. The problem is that the first and second fields are not recognized at the formula and must be converted, and the formula doesn't work. Does anybody could help me with the correct formula to convert the first and second fields and concatenate all fields?

Note: I'm using the simple formula: concat(field1,field2,field3) and it's not working.

Comment: We need some context here. What programming language? What platform?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm talking about Oracle NetSuite.

Comment: There are no fields in Netsuite named field1,field2,field3. Please show as specifically as you can the code you are using

Comment: All 3 fields are custom fields, not native fields, and I named field1, field2 and fild3, just as a example.

Answer (score 2):

In NetSuite you use `||` to concatenate fields.

## Here are two examples:

Code: `{firstname}||{custentity2}||{datecreated}`

Result:[image: {firstname}||{custentity2}||{datecreated}]

Code `'Name:'||{firstname}||' Gender:'||{custentity2}||' Created:'||{datecreated}`

Result:
[image: Name:'||{firstname}||' Gender:'||{custentity2}||' Created:'||{datecreated}]